# How do I fire code after the set time limit is reached using MessageCollecter?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am creating an eval command. I would like it to wait for a response for a maximum of 1 minute. I got that working, but how do I know when the time limit is reached? In the older versions of discord.js, you would normally add a .catch after await-messages. But with version 13, you are recommended to use MessageCollector.
I couldn't find anything about the time limit online.

Here is my code:

```js
interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 60000, max: 1 });
                
              collector.on('collect',async msg => {
                //my eval command
               }
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more minutes of research, I found something!
When defining the collector, it comes with three events. One of them is the "end" event. Example: [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors) when it logs all the collected items.

The code I used:

```js
interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 60000, max: 1 });
                
              collector.on('collect',async msg => {
                //my eval command
               }
collector.on('end',async collected, reason => {
                if(reason == "time"){
                    //make bot say time
                end

               }
```

If you need any help, **comment** below this answer!